# How to create horizontal sub-menu that positions between parent and logo

Tags: html, css, web

Looking for help in creating a navigation menu, where the navigation bar sits above a site logo. I want the sub-menu to expand out of the navigation bar  horizontally and position itself between the parent navigation bar and the logo.

- The sub-menu is horizontal
- The logo is below the navigation bar when collapsed
- The sub-menu will expand out of the navigation bar and push down the position of the logo.

Main navigation:

```
<nav>
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li> <a href="#">One</a>

                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Menu One</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Two</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Three</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Four</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Five</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">Two</a>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">Three</a>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">Four</a>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">Five</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="logo"></div>
```

I have made a mock example here: http://jsfiddle.net/GSfpj/11/ including the CSS I've been playing with.

Instead of the sub-menu expanding underneath the logo, I would like to be able to push the logo downwards and position the sub-menu in between both parent navigation and logo.

I would prefer to do this in pure CSS if possible, any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps do something like this:

```
ul:hover {padding-bottom:25px;}
```

... although, to be honest, I don't think the behavior is vary nice anyway. Why not have the sub menu appear over the top of the logo?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/GSfpj/27/

There are a few things I don't like about this, though:

1. Because the sub-menus need to be taken out of the DOM layout to make the main menu display properly, you need to set them to `position: absolute`. Because of this, you are forced to specify heights, which makes things a bit sloppy and hard to reuse.
2. If you make the `<li>`s `position:relative`, you end up with extra space before the sub-menu. If you instead position the sub-menu relative to the parent `<ul>`, the sub-menu might not even overlap its parent `<li>`, which also brings about issues with the `:hover` state.
3. Because the layout is not done dynamically (you need to explicitly specify heights and padding), you end up with blank space when you hover over a menu item without a submenu.

There really isn't much you can do to get around these issues without getting into javascript or different markup (add classes to represent whether something has a sub-menu or not, etc.)

It works, though, so take it as you will.

Comment: If the sub-menu would instead overlay on top of the logo, would this reduce the complexity and allow the sub menu to position it relative to parent `<ul>`?

Comment: If you overlay the sub-menu, rather than having it push down, it makes everything much simpler. You don't need to explicitly specify heights anymore, the submenus can line up with their parents without looking out-of-place, and you won't see any extra blank space pushing down the logo when no sub-menu exists.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your updated [feddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GSfpj/28/) link. You have to change the following css:

```
ul.menu li {
    display:inline;
    padding:10px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:9999;
}
ul.menu li ul.sub-menu {
    position:absolute;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background:#2f2f2f;
    width:300px;
}
```